# Angular 13 Webpack Exception: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NODE_DEBUG')

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

After upgrading to Angular 13 the application no longer works during runtime.  From what I've read NODE_DEBUG is Webpack specific and for some reason is not recognized when running the application with an 'ng serve'.  I've also recently upgraded to macOS Monterey.  I've very stuck at the moment....

package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~13.1.1",
    "@costlydeveloper/ngx-awesome-popup": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "firebase": "9.6.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jsstore": "4.3.6",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.5.2",
    "ramda": "^0.27.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "service": "^0.1.4",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1301.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "8.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.2",
    "@types/ramda": "0.27.60",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "firebase-tools": "~9.23.1",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^8.2.0",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "^8.4.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.4.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.5.3"
}
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing my Angular.json with a brand new Angular 13 app, I made updates so they matched in structure since ng update did not handle this effectively.  That led me to a new error where I found the NODE_DEBUG was coming from utils.js which was a dependency of jsonwebtoken.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue. I started fresh with angular13 and am using primeng 13.3.3. I am now having this exact error but I cannot figure out why it's happening. Could you be more specific about what change you made that fixed it?

Comment: @ThomasLe were you able to get by this error?

Comment: But how did you fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your node_modules folder and run npm install again.

If still not working try to downgrade the node version to 12.20.x and check.

Comment: No luck.  Wonder if it has something to do with Monterey.  I'll try moving down to Angular 12